# How to open PPTs, PDFs, docs, etc. using default applicaitions by tapping on a button in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to make an app which opens up a PPT, PDF or Docx file using the default application on the device by tapping on a button in my application. If there is no default app, it should open the "Open With" menu.

I tried to use [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file). But it didn't work. I also tried a few other methods I saw on StackOverflow, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open file on Internet you can use package https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

code snippet for url_launcher

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Open File'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://yoursite/sample.pdf';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

To open file in local path 
You can see working demo and full code below

code snippet

```
final filePath = '/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf';
print('${filePath}');
final message = await OpenFile.open(filePath);
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _openResult = 'Unknown';

  Future<void> openFile() async {
    final filePath = '/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf';
    print('${filePath}');
    final message = await OpenFile.open(filePath);

    setState(() {
      _openResult = message;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('open result: $_openResult\n'),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Tap to open file'),
                onPressed: openFile,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Emulator SDCard Download directory has a pdf file

[image]

working demo

[image]